# Why is wifi.sta nil even after wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, esplorer

> EDIT: what I'm trying to do is essentially configure the station after
>   the softap is running a TCP server.

I get a **panic error** for `wifi.sta` being **nil** when I call `wifi.sta.config(station_cfg)` even after I configured it properly before.

When I do:

```
function connectHib()
   wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)
   [AP config here]
   station_cfg={}
   station_cfg.ssid = ""
   station_cfg.pwd = ""
   station_cfg.save = false
   station_cfg.auto = false   
   wifi.sta.config(station_cfg)
end
```

It works fine, but when I call it, then start a server with `srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)` and then call the following function:

```
function validateSTA()
   station_cfg={}
   station_cfg.ssid = _G.wifi
   station_cfg.pwd = _G.senha
   station_cfg.save = false
   station_cfg.auto = false
   wifi.sta.config(station_cfg) -- this creates an error
   wifi.sta.connect()
end
```

It gives me a *PANIC* error on the commented line. I'm just trying to reconfigure the **STATION module only** and then tell it to connect so I can validate the conection.

I'm using:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: master
    commit: 67027c0d05f7e8d1b97104e05a3715f6ebc8d07f
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,file,gpio,net,node,pwm,sjson,tmr,uart,wifi
 build created on 2018-04-16 13:55
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.2.1(cfd48f3)
```

**What bugs me is** why it seems like it has not been "declared" before, *but it works on the first function*... I thought **wifi.** was global like **_G.** variables.

It also works if I call the functions separately on the ESPlorer command line on an ESP without my init.lua.

I also tried the debug firmware and the only odd thing I saw poping up was *wifi_event_monitor_handle_event_cb* that is called every 4 secconds or so.

Thanks guys, any help is apreciated as I'm stuck about a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many other script languages, lua doesn't have declarations, only assignments. 
You should perform checks what is `wifi`'s value during the first and the second calls. It seems that at first you are using it as a table, and in the second function you try to use it as a string in the `station_cfg.ssid = _G.wifi`.

Or the reason is that global variables are not "like `_G`", they're stored in `_G`.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitry. After a while I realised that the real question should be the one in the edit. Anyway I'll check for the values on *wifi* and show you the results.

Comment: Hey @Dimitry. As you suggested I checked the values and realised that I was overwriting _G.wifi by mistake!

It took me long time to tell you cause I also noticed that I was using the server in an old way wich is not suported anymore by the current firmware and it gave me some misleading errors.

I heard that I should use _G. table with caution, but I still dont know the variable names already declared there and, in my code, _G.wifi made total sense to use, but unfortunately it was overwriting the wifi.sta module, that I now know its accessible this way.